# Login form script else part not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I wrote a simple login form script for my web app. The things works fine. I am able to get logged into account if my username and password matches.

My problem is with it doesn't shows the desired message if the details entered are invalid.

The script is as follows

```
<?php
include 'buildconfig.php';

$connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or
die("Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection) or 
die("Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysql_error());

function SignIn()
{
    // username and password sent from form
    $myusername=$_POST['username'];
    $mypassword=$_POST['password'];

    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM members WHERE uname='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error()); 
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($row["uname"] == $myusername && $row["password"] == $mypassword)
        {
            $to_location = "Location:../pages/login.html";header($to_location);
        }
        //this else is not working
        else
        {
            echo"Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.";
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    SignIn();
}
?>
```

Am I doing wrong something?

Or are there better ways to achieve this?

Comment: There is no `$row` in case of a mismatch, hence it does not enter the while loop.

Comment: put ob_start(); at top and cgheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the code is mismatched you wont get any row and for checking that row are present or not use mysqli_num_rows.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)!==0)
```

Use the code below

```
<?php
include 'buildconfig.php';

$connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or
die("Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection) or 
die("Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysql_error());

function SignIn()
{
// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['username'];
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM members WHERE uname='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result === FALSE) {
die(mysql_error()); 
}
if(mysql_num_rows($result)!==0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if($row["uname"] == $myusername && $row["password"] == $mypassword)
{$to_location = "Location:../pages/login.html";header($to_location);}

}
}
//this else is working
else
{echo"Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.";}
}


if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{SignIn();}
?>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score -1):

TJ was correct above. Your error echo is inside of a while loop that will never run. Simply bring it out, you don't even need the if because your headers should redirect if success prior to ever reaching the else statement.

```
<?php
    include 'buildconfig.php';

    $connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysql_error());
    $db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection) or 
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysql_error());

    function SignIn(){
        // username and password sent from form
        $myusername=$_POST['username'];
        $mypassword=$_POST['password'];

        // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
        $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
        $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
        $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
        $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

        $sql="SELECT * FROM members WHERE uname='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if($result === FALSE) {
            die(mysql_error()); 
        }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            if($row["uname"] == $myusername && $row["password"] == $mypassword){
                $to_location = "Location:../pages/login.html";
                header($to_location);
            }
        }

        // this will run after the while loop and in theory the header redirect so no need for else
        echo "Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        SignIn();
    }
?>
```

Comment: why the down vote? uncool considering it is a working and correct answer.

Comment: This answer also works for me... Thank You... Can't say why it is down voted

Comment: Ha, all that matters is that it helped answer the question and get you moving forward :)